# Redirect to login page if login block fails

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

If you fail to log in correctly from a login block, I would like the user to be directed to the login page to log in from there.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Then the other question should be updated to have a more verbose title that is pertinent to the actual question.  I didn't find it specifically for that reason.

Comment: I updated the title of the question being directed to.

Answer (score 0):

I guess altering the user login form and override the [user_login_final_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7) with a custom custom_user_login_final_validate() with all codes copy from existing to custom and adding redirecting codes to login page with a check that current page is not user login page, should work.